# Real-World Example of Correlation of Random Variables

Tags: correlation, intuition

I'm encountering a result in research that is counter-intuitive to me. Specifically, I have two matrics, $X, Y$, where $X_i$ is the ith column of matrix $X$.

In my research:

$\Large{\rho}$$ (\sum X_i, \sum Y_i) < 0$ and statistically significant,

While:

$\Large{\rho}$$ (X_i, Y_i) > 0$ for all columns.

Can anyone provide a real-world example of this happening? I am trying to get to the root cause of this.

Comment: Clearly it's mathematically possible: you have observed it!  What, then, do you mean by "root cause," given that you have presented only mathematical information and no relevant information about your data?

Comment: Fair, I cannot provide the data or explain the context of the problem. But I am trying to understand the why-ness of the problem but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Comment: In other words, you want us to guess without sharing anything about the circumstances!

Answer (score 1):

Not a real-world example,  but I think this is an example that can help you understand.

```
X1 = rnorm(100)
Y1 = 100*X1
X2 = -100*X1
Y2 = -1*X1

SX = X1 + X2
SY = Y1 + Y2

cor(X1, Y1)
[1] 1
cor(X2, Y2)
[1] 1
cor(SX, SY)
[1] -1
```

It is clear what is going on here. Y1 is perfectly correlated with X1. Y2 is perfectly correlated with X2. But X2 is negatively correlated with X1. Because X2 is much bigger than X1, X1+X2 is correlated with X2. Because Y1 is much bigger than Y2, Y1+Y2 is correlated with Y1 (which is correlated with X1).
So the sums are negative correlated even though the summands are positive correlated.

This may be what is happening in your data. Are there differences in the size of some of the X's and in some of the Y's?  Are some of the X's negatively correlated with each other?